# How can I determine how many of an array of ints need to be a non-default value for the total value of the count of items to equal a given value?

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

Given the value I want a number of items to total, how can I programmatically determine how many need to be of an alternate/adjusted value to equal (as close as possible, anyway) the given value?

More specifically, say I had 290 items that needed to total 2700. The default value is 10, but if the given value is less than (item count * 10) - which would be 2900 in this case, a certain number of those items will have to have a value of 9 instead of 10; OTOH, if the given value is *greater* than (item count * 10), a certain number of those items will have to have a value of 11 instead of 10 (for example, if the given value was still 2700, but the item count was 250). Eight and twelve would never be used - only 9, 10, and 11.

In these cases, there would be 200 nines and 90 tens in the first case:

```
200 * 9 == 1800
90 * 10 == 900
           2700
```

...and 200 elevens and 50 tens in the second case:

```
200 * 11 == 2200
50 * 10 == 500
           2700
```

I need a function that will take the given value, and the item count, and return the number of "outliers" (9s or 11s). IOW, the function would look like this:

```
function int GetOutlierCount(int ValToEqual, int ItemCount) {
    // TODO: How?
}
```

...and be called like this:

```
GetOutlierCount(2700, 290)
```

-or:

```
GetOutlierCount(2700, 250)
```

...etc. In both cases shown above, it would return 200, as 200 9s are needed in the first case, and 200 11s in the second case (the caller would know which to expect, based on whether ValToEqual was 10* greater than (ItemCount * 10) or not.

Comment: And what have you tried? Did you get stacked on something? *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions**, why they didn't work, and the expected results.*

Comment: I agree @MarcinJuraszek. I does not sound like you got stock at any point yet. Did you?

Comment: That's exactly where I am "stock" - from the git-go.

Comment: A lot of cats seem to be in a bad mood today for some reason.

Comment: This is seriously obvious maths.

Comment: Rawling, I would be very curious to see the obvious solution. It seems like a integer programming problem to me.

Comment: It's simple given the constraint that the inputs are such that the integers never need to be adjusted by more than one in either direction.

Comment: Rawling, You were right, of course. I didn't realize at first, that the problem had only one variable, and not two as I first imagined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, you have `n` integers each of value `v`.

You have a total `t` that you want to achieve, where `n * (v-1) <= t <= n * (v+1)`.

If `t < n * v`, you have to decrease `(n*v) - t` of your integers by `1` to total `t`.

If `t > n * v`, you have to increase `t - (n*v)` of your integers by `1` to total `t`.

Your first example has `n = 290, v = 10, t = 2700`. `2700 < 290 * 10` holds so you need to adjust `(290*10) - 2700 = 200` of your items downwards.

Your second example has `n = 250, v = 10, t = 2700`. `2700 > 250 * 10` holds so you need to adhust `2700 - (250*10) = 200` of your items upwards.

---

(In case I've not made it obvious enough: the number of items you need to change is simply the difference between your desired total and your actual total.)

Comment: You are correct, but I found it a bit difficult to follow your explanation. But it is quite simple to show that you have `x*v + y*(v-1) = t` and `x+y=n` which gives the equation `x*v + (n-x)*(v-1) = t` with the solution `x = t - (v-1)*n`, and the outlier count `y = n - x`. To me, that was easier to understand.

Comment: And he calls that "simple" - sheesh! (Or "Heavens to Murgatroid!")

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Seriously? "My items add up to 2700, but I need them to add up to 2500. How many of them do I need to reduce by 1? 2700 - 2500 = 200!"

Comment: Actually, it's the other way around (the items that would normally add up to 2900 or 2500 need to be 2700 in the cases outlined), but I see your point.

Answer (score 1):

Brute force implementation. Linear time, so still pretty good. Left here for posterity, since I first mistakenly thought this was a hard problem. :)

```
def outlier_count(target_val, count):
    default_val = 10
    other_val = default_val - 1
    x_max = target_val / default_val

    for x in range(x_max, -1, -1): # x_max, x_max-1, ..., 0
        y = count - x
        if x*default_val + y*other_val == target_val:
            return (x, y)
    raise ValueError("No solution")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function int GetOutliers(int totalVal, int itemsCount) {
        const int DEFAULT_MULTIPLIER = 10;
        int icMultiplied =  itemsCount * DEFAULT_MULTIPLIER;
        return Math.Abs(totalVal - icMultiplied);
}
```